# how do you use a Model variable in an MVC 5 web view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I am have pulled a list of users out of an active directory that have active reports to a current user and have successfully shown the list in a web view table in MVC 5.

However, I am encountering a problem when I try to print the name of the current user above the table in the web view.

Does anyone know how to do this in MVC 5 using the razor view?

This is the code I am using to get the current user from the system:

```
public string getUserName()
{
    displayName = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
    return displayName;
}
```

And the view I am currently working on:

```
@model IEnumerable<BUUK.BSS.Models.User>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "MyTeam";
}
<h2>@ViewBag.Title</h2>
<h3>@ViewBag.Message</h3>

<p>
    ViewBag.Title = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
</p>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Email)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Email)
            </td>
            @*<td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey     */ }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */   })
            </td>*@
        </tr>
    }

</table>
```

Comment: Could you post some code from your view? Also please be more specific about the problem that you are encountering. Do you get any compilation error or runtime exception message?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but where are you actually using `getUserName()`? It does not look to be used anywhere in the code you posted.

Comment: It is called in a method that gets the list from the active directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you simply want to print the name in a view, you should do it like this:

```
<p>
    @System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name
</p>
```

Comment: That works thankyou, can you do this buy calling the C# method?

Comment: Yes, you can. Just put @ before the call to a method.

Comment: How would you add the object reference to the method call? I have added the following code so far: 

'@BUUK.BSS.Models.User.getUserName();'